# After inserting html into contenteditable div, position cursor after insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I can insert html into a contenteditable div just fine using this code:

```
function insertHtmlAtCursor(html) {
    let selection, range, node;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.getRangeAt && selection.rangeCount) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        node = range.createContextualFragment(html);
        range.insertNode(node);
    }
}
```

However, afterwards the cursor is placed within the inserted html.  Instead I need it to be positioned just after the inserted html.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setEndAfter e.g. `range.setEndAfter(node); range.collapse();` might do. Or even https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/collapseToEnd `selection.collapseToEnd();`.

Comment: The first option returned an error, but "selection.collapseToEnd();" works some of the time. For example, if the cursor is at the end of the div when I insert the html, then the cursor ends up inside the html.  It also seems to have some problems if the cursor is touching another word when I insert the html.  Any other suggestions?